# how to set .yarnrc config with nexus repository "401 Unauthorized"

Tags: npm, registry, hadoop-yarn

My package.json file is configured as follows. The 'npm install' command works without any issues

```
{

    ...

    "dependencies": {

        "my-package": "https://nexus.myrepo.co.kr/..."

    },

    ...

}
```

Here is my .yarnrc file I've configured. What might be wrong that's causing the 401 Unauthorized error?

```
{

    npmRegistries: {

        "https://nexus.myrepo.co.kr/...": {

            npmAlwaysAuth: true,

            npmAuthIdent: 'hello:world',

            npmAuthToken: '000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000',

        },

    },

}
```

I've tried configuring 'npmRegistryServer,' 'npmRegistries,' 'npmScopes,' and so on